# Read filenames from a textfile in python (double backslash issue)

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to read a list of files from a text file. I am using the following code to do that:

```
filelist = input("Please Enter the filelist: ")
flist = open (os.path.normpath(filelist),"r")
fname = []
for curline in flist:
    # check if its a coment - do comment parsing in this if block
    if curline.startswith('#'): 
        continue
    fname.append(os.path.normpath(curline));
flist.close() #close the list file

# read the slave files 100MB at a time to generate stokes vectors
tmp = fname[0].rstrip()
t = np.fromfile(tmp,dtype='float',count=100*1000)
```

This works perfectly fine and I get the following array:

```
'H:\\Shaunak\\TerraSAR_X- Sep2012-Glacier_Velocity_Gangotri\\NEST_oregistration\\Glacier_coreg_Cnv\\i_HH_mst_08Oct2012.bin\n'
'H:\\Shaunak\\TerraSAR_X- Sep2012-Glacier_Velocity_Gangotri\\NEST_oregistration\\Glacier_coreg_Cnv\\i_HH_mst_08Oct2012.bin\n'
'H:\\Shaunak\\TerraSAR_X- Sep2012-Glacier_Velocity_Gangotri\\NEST_oregistration\\Glacier_coreg_Cnv\\q_HH_slv3_08Oct2012.bin\n'
'H:\\Shaunak\\TerraSAR_X- Sep2012-Glacier_Velocity_Gangotri\\NEST_oregistration\\Glacier_coreg_Cnv\\q_VV_slv3_08Oct2012.bin'
```

The problem is that the `'\'` charecter is escaped and there is a trailing `'\n'` in the strings. I used the `str.rstrip()` to get rid of the '\n' - this works, but leaves the problem of the two back slashes.

I have used the following approaches to try getting rid of these:

1. Used the `codecs.unicode_escape_decode()` but I get this error:
   `UnicodeDecodeError: 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 56-57: malformed \N character escape`. Clearly this is not the right approach because I just want to decode the backslashed, not the rest of the string.
2. This does not work either: `tmp = fname[0].rstrip().replace(r'\\','\\');`

Is there no way to make readline() read a raw string?

---

UPDATE:

Basically I have a text file with 4 file names I would like to open and read data from in python. The text file contains:

```
H:\Shaunak\TerraSAR_X-Sep2012-Glacier_Velocity_Gangotri\NEST_oregistration\Glacier_coreg_Cnv\i_HH_mst_08Oct2012.bin
H:\Shaunak\TerraSAR_X-Sep2012-Glacier_Velocity_Gangotri\NEST_oregistration\Glacier_coreg_Cnv\i_HH_mst_08Oct2012.bin
H:\Shaunak\TerraSAR_X-Sep2012-Glacier_Velocity_Gangotri\NEST_oregistration\Glacier_coreg_Cnv\q_HH_slv3_08Oct2012.bin
H:\Shaunak\TerraSAR_X-Sep2012-Glacier_Velocity_Gangotri\NEST_oregistration\Glacier_coreg_Cnv\q_VV_slv3_08Oct2012.bin
```

I would like to open each file one by one and read 100MBs of data from them.
When I use this command:`np.fromfile(flist[0],dtype='float',count=100)` I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'H:\\Shaunak\\TerraSAR_X-Sep2012-Glacier_Velocity_Gangotri\\NEST_oregistration\\Glacier_coreg_Cnv\\i_HH_mst_08Oct2012.bin'
```

---

Update

Full Traceback:

```
Please Enter the filelist: H:/Shaunak/TerraSAR_X- Sep2012-Glacier_Velocity_Gangotri/NEST_oregistration/Glacier_coreg_Cnv/filelist.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "G:\WinPython-32bit-3.3.2.3\python-3.3.2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 581, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "G:\WinPython-32bit-3.3.2.3\python-3.3.2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 41, in execfile
    exec(compile(open(filename).read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
  File "H:/Shaunak/Programs/Arnab_glacier_vel/Stokes_generation_2.py", line 28, in <module>
    t = np.fromfile(tmp,dtype='float',count=100*1000)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'H:\\Shaunak\\TerraSAR_X-Sep2012-Glacier_Velocity_Gangotri\\NEST_oregistration\\Glacier_coreg_Cnv\\i_HH_mst_08Oct2012.bin'
>>>
```

Comment: What are you looking for, actually? Can you just provide what output would you like? It's a bit unclear for me.

Comment: Double slash is an internal representation; if you print the entry as an individual string, you'll see the regular single slash. You don't have to do anything with slashes.

Comment: @alKid Question updated.

volcano - I am not able to use these string to read data : np.fromfile(tmp,dtype='float',count=100)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'H:\\Shaunak\\TerraSAR_X-Sep2012-Glacier_Velocity_Gangotri\\NEST_oregistration\\Glacier_coreg_Cnv\\i_HH_mst_08Oct2012.bin'

Comment: @volcano - I need to read these files using the np.fromfile command

Comment: @eternalDreamer, remove \n at the end - and any Python command will recognize the file name properly. As I said - double backslash is the internal representation in Python of real single backlash; single backslash alows you to enter escape sequences in a string, that's why you see double in the representation. As far as functionality is concerned, your strings contain just single slashes

Comment: @volcano - im using str.rstrip()

Comment: @eternalDreamer That will do

Comment: Renaming the directory solved the problem - there was probably some problem with the "-"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @volcano stated, double slash is only an internal representation. If you print it, they're gone. The same if you write it to files, there will only be one '\'.

```
>>> string_with_double_backslash = "Here is a double backslash: \\"
>>> print(string_with_double_backslash)
Here is a double backslash: \
```

Comment: @alKid - Yes but if I want to read the file using np.fromfile(tmp,dtype='float',count=100) - I get an error

Comment: So this is an xy problem. The problem is not with the backslash, can you post the full traceback?

Comment: Please Enter the filelist: H:/Shaunak/TerraSAR_X- Sep2012-Glacier_Velocity_Gangotri/NEST_oregistration/Glacier_coreg_Cnv/filelist.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "G:\WinPython-32bit-3.3.2.3\python-3.3.2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 581, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "G:\WinPython-32bit-3.3.2.3\python-3.3.2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 41, in execfile
    exec(compile(open(filename).read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

Comment: @alkid  File "H:/Shaunak/Programs/Arnab_glacier_vel/Stokes_generation_2.py", line 28, in <module>
    t = np.fromfile(tmp,dtype='float',count=100*1000)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'H:\\Shaunak\\TerraSAR_X-Sep2012-Glacier_Velocity_Gangotri\\NEST_oregistration\\Glacier_coreg_Cnv\\i_HH_mst_08Oct2012.bin'

Comment: Can you post it in the question?

Comment: I think that's simply because the file isn't there. Try `open(path)`. If it throws an error as well, then it's because your path is wrong.

Comment: @alKid It works if I put in the file name without the backslashes

Comment: @alKid - I moved the folders - it worked - is there something wrong with the directory names? Do I have to escape the directory names?

Comment: Renaming the directory solved the problem - there was probably some problem with the "-"

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
a_escaped = 'attachment; filename="Nuovo Cinema Paradiso 1988 Director\\\'s Cut"'
a_unescaped = codecs.getdecoder("unicode_escape")(a)[0]
```

yielding:

```
'attachment; filename="Nuovo Cinema Paradiso 1988 Director\'s Cut"'
```